# User currently viewing launcher app

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have an app that runs on background thread. I need to find out if the user is currently viewing the launcher and not on other app.
on pre Lollipop you could use

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> running = am.getRunningTasks(1);
```

and the first one on the list should have been the currently active app which you could have tested against the list of all installed launchers.

This doesn't work anymore. Is there any other way to find out if the user currently viewing the launcher app or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is the launcher app special? IMHO you should behave the same whether the user is in the launcher or any other app other than yours: gently. If you want to "pick up the pace" of a background thread when your own UI is in the foreground, that's fine, as the user is specifically indicating that they are interested in what your app is doing.

Comment: I need to install several shortcuts, and unless your installing them when the launcher is the current top task, their order is not guaranteed

Comment: Their order is not guaranteed, regardless of circumstance. After all, the home screen launcher does not have to support shortcuts at all. The home screen launcher can do whatever it wants with your shortcut requests: ignore them, sort them based on the third character of the label, invert the colors of your icons, etc.